# More_like_this query only giving me 10 results

Tags: python, apache, elasticsearch, lucene, morelikethis

I am using the More like this query for getting the similarity between medical reports and then put them in a matrix. The problem is that somehow it is only giving me 10 results instead of all of them.

I guess it is giving me the 10 more similar?

We have tried putting a size field and nothing is working.

Also is there a way to show the results divided by the fields? Because I have read it mixes all the fields results to give a final score, but I would also like to get the individual ones

```
def search_similar (self, id_caso):
    return self._es_buscar(
        { 
            "size": 100, 
            "query": { 
                "more_like_this": {
                    "like": [ { "_id": id_caso} ],
                    "fields": self.conf.get('campos'),
                    "max_query_terms": 100,
                    "min_term_freq": 0,
                    "minimum_should_match": 0
                } 
            }    
        })

def _es_buscar (self, query):
    res = self._es.search(index="historiales",
                          doc_type="historial",
                          body=query)
    return [{ 'id': r['_id'], 'doc': r['_source'], 'score' : r['_score']} for r in res['hits']['hits']]
```

I'm only getting 10 results when I'm expecting 32. I don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

The `size` needs to be specified as a [parameter to the `search` method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_search) not inside the query body:

```
res = self._es.search(index="historiales",
                      doc_type="historial",
                      size=100,                      <--- add this
                      body=query)
```